# how to mirror console.log in html page text box

Tags: javascript, html, console.log

Can I allocate a text box in the html page itself to mirror `console.log`* ?

```html
<html><body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function btnclick(id) 
{
    console.log(document.getElementById(id).value);
}
</script>
<table>
<td><input type="button" value="7" id="btn7" onclick="btnclick('btn7');"/></td>
<td><input type="button" value="8" id="btn8" onclick="btnclick('btn8');"/></td>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" value="4" id="btn4" onclick="btnclick('btn4');"/></td>
<td><input type="button" value="5" id="btn5" onclick="btnclick('btn5');"/></td>
</tr>
</table></body></html>
```

---

*`console.log` here simply echoes the pressed number

Comment: Where's your text box? You can just add the textbox update to `btnclick()`

Comment: @mykaf not sure what you mean

Comment: a.) there is no textbox in the html presented. b.) once you have said textbox, you'll need to write code to update your textbox. `console.log()` itself won't update your textbox, but you can replace `console.log()` with `btnclick()` or whatever function to quickly do both.

Comment: @MosheKatz I don't want a stack of values - I want to see just the *last* logged line